# Passing unknown link variables to a new page

Tags: php, get, hyperlink

I have a link, an offer page and a destination page. I need to carry the variables from the original link and input them into the links on the offer page.

original link

```
www.example.com/offerpage.php?offer=1&aff_id=var1&aff_sub=var2
```

Where you see var1 and var2, those could be any number.

I'm assuming I could do something like this (this is a total guess, just want to make sure I do it correctly).

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('aff_id', $_GET)){
        $aff_id = $_GET;
    } 
    else {
        $aff_id = '1';
    }

?>
```

Then the links on the offer page would be

```
www.offer.com/index.php?offer=1&aff_id=<?php echo $aff_id; ?>&aff_sub=<?php echo $aff_sub; ?>
```

and whats the correct format for doing multiples?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiples"? And what exactly is your question anyway? Did you try your attempt?

Comment: Yea, mine doesn't work. I'm wondering what exactly i'm doing wrong.

Comment: @str i mean how do i correctly format doing 3 of these in one link

Comment: Use `$aff_id = $_GET['aff_id'];`.

Comment: @OneEightLeft: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do what you want:

```
if (!array_key_exists('aff_id', $_GET)) {
    $_GET['aff_id'] = 1;
}
echo http_build_query($_GET);
```

If the query string is `offerpage.php?offer=1&aff_id=var1&aff_sub=var2`then the output will be:

```
offer=1&aff_id=var1&aff_sub=var2
```

And, if the query string doesn't contain `aff_id`, i.e. `offerpage.php?offer=1&aff_sub=var2` then the output will be:

```
offer=1&aff_sub=var2&aff_id=1
```